# Edit post in vue js, axios, django

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I start coding in vuetify and want to make Edit button who get the data of selected id, response selected post from axios and transfer it to another components.

I trying props but its not working here, or i do something wronk with it.

There is my List and Edit components:

```js
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12">
        <v-list shaped>
          <v-list-item-group color="deep-purple" v-model="selected" multiple>
            <v-list-item v-for="item in todoList" :key="item.id">
              <v-list-item-icon>
                {{ item.id }}
              </v-list-item-icon>

              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>
                  <strong>{{ item.title }}</strong>
                </v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
              <v-btn fab dark small color="purple">
                <v-icon dark @click="Edit()"> mdi-pencil </v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list-item-group>
        </v-list>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "BookList",
  data: () => ({
    selected: [],
    todoList: [],
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.getTodos();
  },
  methods: {
    getTodos() {
      axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todo/").then((response) => {
        this.todoList = response.data;
      });
    },
    Edit() {
      this.$emit("title", this.item.title);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```js
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12">
        <v-form>
          <v-text-field
            v-model="this.title"
            :counter="64"
            label="title"
            required
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-form>
      </v-col>
      <v-btn @click="edit" color="success" class="mr-4"> Edit </v-btn>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => {
    return {
      title: this.title,
    };
  },
  components: {},
  mounted() {},
  methods: {},
};
</script>
```

but i stuck. I think i do somethink wrong with Emit medo but dont know what. Can u give some hint what to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can use store to store the api response on edit button click and access that store data in the `EditItem` route page.